# Is there any way I can administer a Mac OS X Server 10.6 from a client running Mac OS X 10.4 or 10.5?

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, remote-access

This is really annoying... I need to administer a Mini Server running Mac OS X Server 10.6. Should be easy by using the Server Admin Tools I thought, but no. To administer a server running Mac OS X Server 10.6, I need Server Admin Tools version 10.6. Fair enough. But, to run Server Admin Tools version 10.6 I need Mac OS X version 10.6?! Coming from a Windows world, that makes no sense to me what so ever. Isn't Server Admin Tools just an app? What makes it even more annoying is that to get Mac OS X 10.6, I need Intel, and we have no macs running Intel here yet.

Soo... what can I do here? How can I administer that server? What are my options? Do I have any options at all? Or do I seriously need to buy another mac just to administer that mac server?

***Note:*** I know I can put a screen on it, but it's location is so that that would not really be a workable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use remote desktop. If you know the ip (or hostname), then in finder, use the Go menu, and then connect to server. You would want to connect to **vnc://ip** or **vnc://hostname**

Comment: Not quite the same style as the Mac server manager tool, but in that case that's probably the best you're gonna get. Voted up.

Comment: This should do the trick. I use it every day between my macs. Server Admin Tools are somewhat overkill when you just need a remote desktop.

Comment: Do I need to have Remote Desktop installed for that to work, or can Mac OS X open up vnc connections like that by default?

Comment: Hm, when I did that it says: *Connecting to afp://vnc//ip* and I get a window called *AFP Connection Status* where it says *Looking up "vnc."... That just doesn't look right :p (have made sure that I actually did write *vnc://ip* and not *vnc//ip*)

Comment: It shouldn't include the afp:// part if you're typing it correctly. afp:// is for file sharing. I don't believe that you need any remote desktop applications installed as well.

Answer (score 1):

I use a combination of remote desktop and the terminal to administer a 10.6 server. All admin features are available through the terminal, which is essentially independent of the OS on your client machine.

Answer (score -1):

Apple is a company that doesn't believe in or pay attention to the past.

What is this 10.4 or 10.5 thing that you speak of? Is that a new beta of Snow Leopard's successor or something?

Comment: I suppose that's why patches came out for 10.4 as recently as November?

Comment: Oh boy, the Apple zealots come out to tar and feather anyone who isn't sufficiently worshipful. I manage about 500 Macs at work -- so I know a little something about this. There may have been a patch released for 10.4 3 months ago, but you still can't use the Apple tools to manage an Apple server. Typically even for a fairly large customer, Apple doesn't provide much support for backlevel versions.